# What is default Password for Live Session User in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: live-usb, password

I am booting 18.10 on USB. I want to protect the the account with a password that is not default by creating an account when I boot Ubuntu.

Comment: The live session user on an Ubuntu installer USB has no password, and you can also not really change it, as it is not persistent. It also doesn't really make sense to set a password on a generic live system because of that very reason.

Comment: What about protecting the account I am using while i am using it?

Comment: If you are using a Persistent install you can go to Settings / Details / Users, and create your own user account and specify your own password. There is no need for a password on a Live USB as no changes are saved from boot to boot.

Answer (score 4):

The live CD/USB default username is 'ubuntu' and the password is just blank.